# Spark jobs fails on EMR Cluster for large file

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I am running a spark job on my EMR cluster. The Data size is 11GB. The issue is the my Jobs fails and the reason is I guess OOM. I am not able to understand why is it giving that when I have given decent Compute to the clusters.

Pleas help and suggest what did I do wrong.

In my spark job I am just reading data from s3 and writing it back to s3.
The jobs runs fine on smaller dataset

**Error**

```
ERROR:root:Exception while sending command.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1649827912085_0005/container_1649827912085_0005_01_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1159, in send_command
    raise Py4JNetworkError("Answer from Java side is empty")
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Answer from Java side is empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1649827912085_0005/container_1649827912085_0005_01_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 985, in send_command
    response = connection.send_command(command)
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1649827912085_0005/container_1649827912085_0005_01_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1164, in send_command
    "Error while receiving", e, proto.ERROR_ON_RECEIVE)
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Error while receiving
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "emr_test_prediction-2.py", line 54, in <module>
    sql_final_result.write.csv('s3://emrtestbucketvirginia/emr_test_files/outputEmr/')
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1649827912085_0005/container_1649827912085_0005_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 935, in csv
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1649827912085_0005/container_1649827912085_0005_01_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1649827912085_0005/container_1649827912085_0005_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1649827912085_0005/container_1649827912085_0005_01_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 336, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o93.csv
ERROR:py4j.java_gateway:An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:35037)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1649827912085_0005/container_1649827912085_0005_01_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 929, in _get_connection
    connection = self.deque.pop()
IndexError: pop from an empty deque
```

**Cluster Config:**

**Master:**

```
m5.xlarge
4 vCore, 16 GiB memory, EBS only storage
EBS Storage:64 GiB
Maximum Spot price: 100 % of On-demand price
Each instance counts as1units
```

**Core**

```
c3.8xlarge
32 vCore, 60 GiB memory, 640 SSD GB storage
EBS Storage:none
Maximum Spot price: 100 % of On-demand price
Each instance counts as32units

m5.xlarge
4 vCore, 16 GiB memory, EBS only storage
EBS Storage:64 GiB
Maximum Spot price: 100 % of On-demand price
Each instance counts as4units
```

**Task**

```
c3.8xlarge
32 vCore, 60 GiB memory, 640 SSD GB storage
EBS Storage:none
Maximum Spot price: 100 % of On-demand price
Each instance counts as32units

c3.4xlarge
16 vCore, 30 GiB memory, 320 SSD GB storage
EBS Storage:none
Maximum Spot price: 100 % of On-demand price
Each instance counts as16units

c3.xlarge
4 vCore, 7.5 GiB memory, 80 SSD GB storage
EBS Storage:none
Maximum Spot price: 100 % of On-demand price
Each instance counts as4units

m5.xlarge
4 vCore, 16 GiB memory, EBS only storage
EBS Storage:64 GiB
Maximum Spot price: 100 % of On-demand price
Each instance counts as4units

c3.2xlarge
8 vCore, 15 GiB memory, 160 SSD GB storage
EBS Storage:none
Maximum Spot price: 100 % of On-demand price
Each instance counts as8units
```

Comment: How did you read and write?

Comment: @pltc I was able to solve it , in my spark script I made some changes